# make array from string by converting datatype using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The `string` I have is as like as follows

```
let a = "0j (0.001953125+0j) (-0.001953125+0.001953125j) (0.998046875+0j) (-0.001953125+0j) (0.001953125+0j) (0+0.0914587j)"
```

Info about the `string`:
1/ Each `substring` is `complex number` in the format of `a+bj`
2/ Possible format of the `complex number` could be `a+bj`,`a`,`bj`. Eg: `1+2j`, `1`,`2j`
3/ There is a space( ) between each `substring`
4/ I have seen that `0+bj`(eg: `0+5j`) or `a+0j`(eg: `5+0j`) format is not possible/ created by the backend so this type of `format/ presentation` is not considered for my case.
5/ If the `substring` contains only `real/imaginary` part then `parenthesis ()` will not be used. Eg: `(5)`,`(5j)` is not possible. They will be `5`,`5j`

I need to create a JSON or JavaScript object from that string which will be used to plot data. The data is coming from the `Flask backend` and it is different for `each request`. One approach I have found to make this JSON object is from an **array** which should look like

```
let my_array = [[0,0], [0.001953125,0], [-0.001953125,0.001953125], [0.998046875,0],[-0.001953125,0],[-0.001953125,0],[0,0.914587]]
```

But I am totally lost in making of this array. Initially, I have removed all the `j` from the string by `a.replaceAll("j","")` but then I have not found a way to make my desired array structure. If I get the array, I can make the JSON object with the following approach:

```js
my_array = [[0,0], [0.001953125,0], [-0.001953125,0.001953125], [0.998046875,0],[-0.001953125,0],[-0.001953125,0],[0,0.914587]]
temp_key = ["i", "q"]
my_json = {
  
}
for(let a = 0; a < my_array.length; a++){
    temp_json = {};
    for(let b = 0; b < my_array[a].length; b++){
        temp_json[temp_key[b]] = my_array[a][b];
}
my_json[String(a)] = temp_json;
}

console.log("my_json: ",my_json)
```

Suggestions regarding making this array will be appreciated.

Comment: What `j` is for and what about `+`? Initially I thought j = `0` as a separate number, but then it's ignored in 3nd group?

Comment: `0.0.914587j` looks like typo? Did you mean `0.0914587j`?

Comment: I think the question is unclear. Are values like `5j`, `5`, `-5-1j`, `-5j+2` or `+5-1j` possible?

Comment: @vanowm `j` is for imaginary part. The data is coming from Python Backend as string. `+` is also presentation type **a+bj**

Comment: @jabaa no it is not possible. And I guess question is not unclear in general.

Comment: No, the question is not unclear in general but the details are important to parse a string. The current answer doesn't work with `5` and `-5j+2` as I would expect and would be wrong if the server could send this values.

Comment: @jabaa each `substring` is a complex number. So in terms of this (-5j+2) is not correct format. You have to chose `a+bj`.  You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/atifkarim/3scp94ar/2/).

Comment: That's what I meant with "your question is unclear". Examples don't describe all possible cases. `-5j+2` is a valid complex number and supported by most languages and libraries that support complex numbers. The given answer doesn't work as you expected because your question was unclear.

Comment: @jabaa Ok, I am trying to rephrase the question

Comment: You should add a description for the pattern and the best way to describe a pattern is a [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). Don't describe a pattern just with examples. But to be honest after you described it this way you'll probably be able to implement the parser yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can split by whitespace, then use a regular expression to match digit characters in the substring (eg `0.001953125+0j` to `0.001953125` and `0`).

```js
const str = "0j (0.001953125+0j) (-0.001953125+0.001953125j) (0.998046875+0j) (-0.001953125+0j) (0.001953125+0j) (0+0.914587j)";
const arr = str
  .split(' ')
  .map((substr) => {
    const [real, imag = 0] = substr.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number);
    return [real, imag];
  });
console.log(arr);
```

`-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` is:

- `-?` - possibly match a leading `-`
- `\d+` - match one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - optionally match the following (the decimal part of a number):

  - `\.` - a literal `.`
  - `\d+` - one or more digits

Comment: Your approach is solved most of the cases. But what about it `const str = "5j";`? For this I expect

`{
  0: {
    i: 0,
    q: 5
  }
}`

But I am getting  

`{
  0: {
    i: 5,
    q: 0
  }
}`

`i,q` format is not desirable. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: That first substring does not match the format of all of the rest in parentheses. Does it have any other possible format, or is `\dj` the only possible substring there?

Comment: possible format of the `substring` could be `a+bj`, `a` or `bj`. Already I have tested with your solution that `a+bj`, `a` working fine. But while `bj` comes then it cannot distinguish between `real` and `imaginary` parts.